# bootstrap x-editable should show value + text in select

Tags: drop-down-menu, x-editable

i have an array defined this way to populate a bootstrap editable dropdown (x-editable)

```
$alist="[{value:'64000',text:'Depreciation Expense'},{value:'67600',text:'Payment Processing Exp.'},{value:'67650',text:'Consulting Services'},{value:'67670',text:'Translations'},{value:'67690',text:'Cash Pickup - Collection'},{value:'67700',text:'Bank Expenses'},{value:'67800',text:'Financial Income/Loss'},{value:'67900',text:'Exceptional Item'},{value:'68000',text:'FX Gain/Loss'},{value:'90000',text:'Year Profit/Loss'}]";
```

html showing the dropdown:

```
 <td><a href="#" id="account_number" data-source="<?php echo $alist;?>" data-type="select" data-pk="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-url="ajax.php" ><?php echo $row['account_number']; ?></a></td>
```

i could do it by getting the account number in my ajax.php processing file, but is there a way to do it directly?

when displaying the dropdown list I would like to have the selection showing value and text (ex "67650-Payment Processing Services) but to have only the value registered (67650)